# Why is OpenGL creating a completely unresponsive window?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL with C++ and Visual Studio; I got a little sick of trying to work with all the added layers of Unity's graphics and just wanted to make something simple myself, and realized real quick that Vulkan was a bit over my head. I happened across this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45MIykWJ-C4

It was pretty helpful for about 20 minutes; however, once it got to rendering a triangle my computer ran into an issue. Despite no compiler errors and basically copy-paste code from the video, upon running the program a window opens up that is completely unresponsive. Sometimes the proper background color will load, but no triangle has worked yet. I cannot interact with this window, not even to move it around or close it. Closing it only happens when I click the x on the debug window that pops up when you run a VS project in debug mode.

If I reopen the solution and run it again, the first time I run it the compiler WILL throw a set of linker warnings about pdb files for glfw being missing; however, they disappear on subsequent runs. I don't know if I should ignore this or not, but I am rather intimidated by file problems and struggle to wrap my head around all the dependencies and linkers and repositories and sources and whatnot; I don't have anyone to teach me, so I only have a glimmer of the basics of this and it all sounds the same to me. I have no idea where to get the pdb files, or where to put them, or even what they are.

I'm extremely frustrated because I've tried for several weeks now to just make a basic game engine and every time I hit a roadblock. I really want to learn this stuff and I hate being always stuck somewhere around step 1. On no tutorial yet have I been able to just render a stupid triangle on the screen because something isn't explained about file organization or compilation or it just goes right over my head. I'm not stupid, but I really feel a bit like a failure for not even being able to do this stuff, and I don't even know what to do at this point when the best tutorial I've found so far still doesn't work and for no apparent reason. The next tutorial I tried organized the dependency libraries differently and just trying to open a window threw 20+ errors and I just don't have the will to even try to sort that out anymore.

I'll link the code below; the various header files are just the tutorial's way of organizing the vertex array object, vertex buffer object, and basic shader program to just render the triangle. I did everything exactly as shown in the tutorial. Please help, and thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include"shaderClass.h"
#include "VAO.h"
#include "VBO.h"
#include "EBO.h"
```

```
int main()
{
    //triangle vertices
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) * 2, 0.0f,
        -0.5f / 2, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 6, 0.0f,
        0.5f / 2, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 6, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) * 2 / 3, 0.0f,
    };`

    GLuint indices[]
    {
        0, 3, 5,
        3, 2, 4,
        5, 4, 1
    };

    glfwInit();

    //hints for GLFW to understand the OpenGL version we are using (OpenGL 3.3) and the CORE profile
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    //initialize a window object, 800 by 800 pixels
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "OpenGL Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    //use the window object in the current OpenGL context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //load GLAD to configure OpenGL
    gladLoadGL();
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);

    Shader shaderProgram("default.vert", "default.frag");

    VAO VAO1;
    VAO1.Bind();

    VBO VBO1(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    EBO EBO1(indices, sizeof(indices));

    VAO1.LinkVBO(VBO1, 0);
    VAO1.Unbind();
    VBO1.Unbind();
    EBO1.Unbind();
    
    
    //main while loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window));
    {
        
        glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shaderProgram.Activate();
        VAO1.Bind();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        //handle glfw events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    //cleanup
    VAO1.Delete();
    VBO1.Delete();
    EBO1.Delete();
    shaderProgram.Delete();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: EBO is not part of VAO state, so you should bind it before calling `glDrawElements`. If you remove all the drawing code, just clear + swap + poll, you should get a colored window, is that not the case for you? PDB files contain debug information, they are not needed. I can really recommend [learnopengl.com](learnopengl.com) .

Comment: @Quimby I think it is. `EBO1.Unbind()` is called after `VAO1.Unbind()`. Likely `EBO1.Unbind()` is useless (or cuases an error)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Not sure about the error, but it needs to be bound for any drawing. It is also slightly concerning that CTORs accept a pointer + total size of the array in bytes, instead of number of elements.

Comment: @Quimby No. The Index buffer is stated  in the VAO! See [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). It is sufficient to bind the VAO.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Really? Okay, my bad then.

Comment: I tried binding and unbinding EBO1, and just doing neither; it didn't have any effect. A blank, unresponsive window still opens :(

Comment: I also tried removing the `shaderProgram.Active();` , `VAO1.Bind()` , and `glDrawElements` calls from the main while loop at the bottom, with no changes in the result

Comment: I'd start from the simplest: Create a glfw window and color it at some not white not black. Nor shaders nor buffers yet. Then add `glad`. Then add shaders. In the journey, by watching every error/warning, you'll discover the `.lib` or `.dll` library-files you need to link on.

Comment: @Ripi2 I did do this; the tutorial starts just like this, but my window was never responsive. At one before messing with the buffers and shaders the window WOULD be colored navy blue like the tutorial, but it never was responsive, never rendered a triangle, and now is just blank white. Maybe I should just start over anyway, might check out the learnopengl site and see how that works out

Comment: @WillMungas The problem is with your system, but not with your code. Is your graphics driver up to date?

Comment: I just updated it to the latest driver and the program still creates an unresponsive empty window :( its for OpenGL 3.3 as well so it should work even if had an older GPU; it's an RX 570, idk if that's considered old yet or not but I've only had it for three or so years

Comment: Thank you all for the responses btw I might not be getting anywhere but it's nice to have some support and ideas to try

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unresponsive? Can you post a screenshot? What if you copy and use just the code posted [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.2.hello_triangle_indexed/hello_triangle_indexed.cpp)?

Comment: @Quimby that code works so I can probably just move forward from there, thank you :); what I mean by unresponsive is that the window is there, but is greyed out and I cannot click any part of it including the X button and I cannot move it, like when a game or app stops responding

Comment: @WillMungas Glad to hear that. I see, that definitely should not happen. And it definitely is out of scope OpenGL. Unless you have endless loop somewhere, look for GLFW settings.

Comment: @WillMungas WAIT a minute, `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window));` <----- is that semi-colon?! Oh well, problem solved then I guess :D That's painful, I'm so sorry :D

Comment: OH NO THATS WHAT IT WAS lmaooooo